# How to sort books in java

Tags: java, sorting, compare

I have some issues with my code. I create a book object and add some chapters to it. The chapters have a chapter number and a name. 
I try to sort the books by the lenght of the chapter name, but it does not work. Can anyone see why? The problem seem to be in the sort-method.

Edit:
The error message I get is this

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at TestProgram.Book$2.compare(Book.java:52)
at TestProgram.Book$2.compare(Book.java:49)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:351)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:216)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1435)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:230)
at TestProgram.Book.sort(Book.java:36)
at TestProgram.Book.sortByTextLenght(Book.java:49)
at TestProgram.Testprogram.main(TestProgram.java:60)
```

In TestProgram:

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book b = Book.createTestBook();                       
        b.sortByTextLenght();
        printBook(b);         
    }

    private static void printBook(Book b) {  
        ArrayList<Chapter> chapters = b.getAllChapters();
        for (Chapter c : chapters) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }    
}
```

In class Book:

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private ArrayList<Chapter> chapters;

    public Book(String title, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();         }

    public static Book createTestBook() {
        Book book = new Book("My first book", "John Johnson");            
        Chapter chapter = new Chapter(5, "The trip");
        book.addChapter(chapter);        
        chapter = new Chapter(2, "The child");
        book.addChapter(chapter);        
        chapter = new Chapter(1, "Finally");
        book.addChapter(chapter);
        chapter = new Chapter(8, "The house");
        book.addChapter(chapter);
        chapter = new Chapter(3, "The boat ride");
        book.addChapter(chapter);            
        return book;
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<Chapter> sortOrder) {  //Problem seem to be here
        Collections.sort(chapters, sortOrder);
    }

    public void sortByTextLenght() {
        sort(new Comparator<Chapter>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Chapter c1, Chapter c2) {
                System.out.println(c2.getText().length() - c1.getText().length());
                return c2.getText().length() - c1.getText().length();
            }
        });
    }               

    public ArrayList<Chapter> getAllChapters() {
        return chapters;
    }
}
```

Comment: "It does not work" - in what way, exactly? Crash? Stack trace?

Comment: See my updated information for the error message I get

Comment: Please post the code that's not working. This works fine when I add a simple implementation for the `Chapter` class and an `addChapter` implementation to `Book`.

Comment: The Exception Stack posted says like Exception occured "at TestProgram.Testprogram.main(TestProgram.java:60) " BUT Where is this "TestProgram" class ..?

Comment: I have an addChapter method and also a Chapter class. The problem is in sort-method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well for me with a Chapter class I've made:

```
class Chapter {
  private int num;
  private String text;
  public Chapter(int i,String s) { num = i; text = s; }
  public String getText() { return text; }
  public String toString() { return text; }
}
```

I also implemented the addChapter method this way:

```
public void addChapter(Chapter c) { chapters.add(c); }
```

The output is :

```
-1
2
1
-1
0
-5
-4
-4
The boat ride
The child
The house
The trip
Finally
```

Comment: I have a Chapter class too. The problem is that it does not print the sorted list. The error seem to be in the sort-method. See error message above.

Comment: For me also. Seems the Problem lies with the "TestProgram" class as the stacktrace suggest, but the OP has made no mention of it in his posting.

Comment: TestProgram and TestClass is the same. My mistake, I have changed it now.
I still can´t get it to work, its weird you guys can :-(

Comment: Solved! It was a small mistake by me in the code. Thanks all for your time

Answer (score 0):

The method `addChapter` is not defined in class `Book`. That's why you get a null pointer because the chapter was not added and you are trying to sort on an attribute that does not exist.

Comment: I do have the method addChapter. I did not paste all methods since they are so many in the real program

Comment: Well you should because it's possibly the root of problem

Comment: Sorry my bad, but the chapter object is returning null somewhere, I suggest adding a breakpoint at the static method and stepping over line by line to see the value of the object `chapter` and if the object is being added to the `book` object.

Comment: objects are being added (I hava Another sorting method that sorts on chapter number, and it works fine). Thanks for trying to help me